# How can I extract random characters from a string?

Tags: r

I have a list of strings:

```
thzJqGVnDxGzyUPZ8r5z
4JfDZijTxDMKBANKPvw1
t7X5C4Nubv8oGIcPEhIc
ZKwBEZBC5IDfm6atAzTG
gIZRkF6XvlOEI8GI2T8l
```

I wish to extract ten characters at random from each string.

For example, the output should look something like this (note that order is irrelevant - just so long as it's a sample):

```
tzJqVDGyZz
fDjTDKAKw1
t7X58oGIhI
ZKwBEatzTG
gIZ8GI2T8l
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Note: there should be no replacement (i.e. once a character has been chosen, it cannot be replaced and chosen again).

In the case of a string containing more than one instance of any character, each character should be treated as independent / an individual.

For example: the string `AABBCCDDEE1122334455` can have a valid result of `AABB44DD2E`.

The result can never be `AAABB44DD2` as this would include an additional `A` which was not present in the original string.

Comment: Could you specify whether a character should be able to be picked multiple times during sampling?

Comment: Something like this? `paste0(sample(strsplit('gdfsgdfyhdfjdfhsgdjyjyhf', '')[[1]], 10), collapse = '')`

Comment: @Sandwichnick Characters may not be replaced but identical characters to others are acceptable. I have clarified this in the question and have added an example also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `utf8ToInt` + `sample`

```
sapply(s,
    function(v) intToUtf8(utf8ToInt(v)[sort(sample(nchar(v), 10))]),
    USE.NAMES = FALSE
)
```

which gives result like

```
[1] "hJnDxGzUPr" "ZjTxAKPvw1" "7C4vIcEhIc" "ZKBEZBImtz" "gIRkvlE2T8"
```

---

If you don't care about keeping the same relative order among characters, you can omit `sort` in the code above

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
x <- "dkdkdkdkdkdk"
nums <- sample(1:nchar(x), 10, replace = FALSE)
output <- paste0(strsplit(x, "")[[1]][nums], collapse="")
```

Answer (score 0):

split your words in characters then make sample of length 10 and paste it together:

```
as.character(lapply(strsplit(words,split = ""), function(x) paste0(sample(x, 10, replace = FALSE), collapse = "")))
```

data:

```
words <- c(
"thzJqGVnDxGzyUPZ8r5z",
"4JfDZijTxDMKBANKPvw1",
"t7X5C4Nubv8oGIcPEhIc",
"ZKwBEZBC5IDfm6atAzTG",
"gIZRkF6XvlOEI8GI2T8l")
```

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with `regmatches()`:

```
sapply(
  regmatches(
    input, 
    lapply(
      input, 
      \(x) {
        output <- sort(sample(seq_len(nchar(x)), 10L))
        attr(output, 'match.length') <- rep(1L, 10L)
        output
      }
    )
  ), 
  \(x) paste(x, collapse = '')
)

# [1] "zJGnxzZ8r5" "fZTDKBNPv1" "tC48ocPhIc" "ZKBEC5fmTG" "gIkFXvOEGl"
```